# How to show module $\mathbb{Z}_6$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ is decomposable

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Decomposable: $\exists$ submodules $L,N \subset M$ s,t $M = L\oplus N$.
$$| \mathbb{Z}_6| = 6 \implies |L|=1,2,3,6 $$
$$\implies \mathbb{Z}_3,\mathbb{Z}_2,0 \subset \mathbb{Z}_6$$
I know $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3=${$(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1),(0,2),(1,2)$} $$ $$
From reading online I found $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3=\mathbb{Z}_6$. But how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More precisely,
$$
\mathbb{Z}_6=3\mathbb{Z}_6\oplus2\mathbb{Z}_6
$$
and the two subgroups are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3$ respectively.

Note that
$$
3\mathbb{Z}_6=\{0,3\}
\qquad
2\mathbb{Z}_6=\{0,2,4\}
$$
Their intersection is $\{0\}$ and their sum is $\mathbb{Z}_6$, because $1=3+4$ and $5=3+2$.